# Problem with inserting values in dictionary

Tags: python, list, dictionary, python-3.6

Facing problem in inserting values in a dictionary which is a member in list.
When i take the user input for an index, it chages the values for all the indexes.

```py
nisl = int(input())
isl = [{'x1':None,'y1':None,'x2':None,'y2':None,}]*nisl
# isl = []
# ship[0]['x'] = '1'
for i in range(nisl):
    isl[i]['x1'],isl[i]['y1'],isl[i]['x2'],isl[i]['y2'] = map(int, input().split(' '))
    print(isl)
```

The output I am getting:

```
2
0 0 1 1
[{'x1': 0, 'y1': 0, 'x2': 1, 'y2': 1}, {'x1': 0, 'y1': 0, 'x2': 1, 'y2': 1}]
3 0 1 4
[{'x1': 3, 'y1': 0, 'x2': 1, 'y2': 4}, {'x1': 3, 'y1': 0, 'x2': 1, 'y2': 4}]
```

What i expected:

```
2
0 0 1 1
[{'x1': 0, 'y1': 0, 'x2': 1, 'y2': 1}, {'x1': None, 'y1': None, 'x2': None, 'y2': None}]
3 0 1 4
[{'x1': 0, 'y1': 0, 'x2': 1, 'y2': 1}, {'x1': 3, 'y1': 0, 'x2': 1, 'y2': 4}]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use:

```
isl = [{'x1': None, 'y1': None, 'x2': None, 'y2': None,} for _ in range(nisl)]
```

instead of:

```
isl = [{'x1':None,'y1':None,'x2':None,'y2':None,}]*nisl
```

The problem is that you created a list of dictionaries where each dictionary has the same reference. Hence, when one changes it reflects in the other as well.

As a solution, create different dictionaries as shown in the first code snippet.